# Best way to authentificate Java sever app

Tags: spring, security, jwt

I have created a Java Spring app with the idea to work as a server app for a web app (build with angularjs or reactjs, not defined yet) and a mobile app without any security concern. Now, I need to add security/authentification functionality. I was looking for the best approach for this, and I found that I could use JWT (JSON web token) for it.
My questions:

1. Is JWT ok for this approach? I mean, for my own authentification
   system using a database, not just facebook/google login.
2. Is it better to start again having an app with the authentification
   working and then add the business functionality (not too much) or it
   is better to add the authentification to my existing app?
3. Do you have any example, step by step tutorial? I cannot find one that do
   what I'm expecting.

Answer (score 0):

1. JWTs are a very good authorizantion method for mobile apps. The two main advantages of JWTs in my opinion are: The user has to login just once and fewer database accesses are necessary (of course it depends on your implementation).
2. I always start with authorization first. I think this way you get cleaner code, but you have to decide if it is worth in your case to start new.
3. If you understand the basic concept of the JWT ([JWT introduction](https://jwt.io/introduction/)) you just need a Java library ([JWT libraries](https://jwt.io/#libraries)) and you will understand the description in the repository good enough to use it.